# Undefined reference to `gdk_color_parse'

Tags: c, compiler-errors, gtk, undefined-reference, gdk

I'm using GTK + 3.0 Lib, and I'm getting errors:

> Undefined reference to `gdk_color_parse'

My source code:

```
int
connectPS3(GtkWidget *button)
{
    HINSTANCE   hLib;
    hLib = LoadLibrary("CCAPI.DLL");

    gchar   *ip;
    ip = "192.168.0.40";

     __cConnect v_connectPS3 = GetProcAddress(hLib, "CCAPIConnectConsole");
    __cNotify v_notifyPS3 = GetProcAddress(hLib, "CCAPIVshNotify");

    GdkColor    color;

    if (v_connectPS3(ip) == 0)
    {
        v_notifyPS3(TROPHY2, "Connected to PS3");
        gtk_button_set_label(GTK_BUTTON(button), "Connected");
        gdk_color_parse("green", &color);
        gtk_widget_modify_bg(button, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
    }
    else
    {
        gtk_button_set_label(GTK_BUTTON(button), "Can't connect to IP Address");
        gdk_color_parse("red", &color);
        gtk_widget_modify_bg(button, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

So if someone can tell me why I'm getting that, I'll be thankful.

I have no linker settings.

Comment: What do you mean `( I have no linker settings )`?

Comment: Please check the existence of the required libraries and please check that they are present in correct order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12434568/2173917) previous answer, it looks like there is some change required in your compilation statement.

However, in general, please check the below points,

1. All the libraries which are used (*required*) should be linked with.
2. [The order of appearance of libraries matter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30870863/2173917), so re-check the order in regards to the dependency.